# Go 1.5+ : Error - imports runtime: C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG

Tags: c, go, build, compilation

My program was building perfectly with go 1.4.2. After installing go 1.5, I am getting following error.

> imports runtime: C source files not allowed when not using cgo or
>   SWIG: atomic_amd64x.c defs.c float.c heapdump.c lfstack.c malloc.c
>   mcache.c mcentral.c mem_linux.c mfixalloc.c mgc0.c mheap.c msize.c
>   os_linux.c panic.c parfor.c proc.c runtime.c signal.c signal_amd64x.c
>   signal_unix.c stack.c string.c sys_x86.c vdso_linux_amd64.c

The error is not program dependent. Even a "Hello world" programs is throwing the same error.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Remove Old 1.4.x go installation and then install go 1.5.

I faced the same problem after installing go 1.5. The issue is that I installed go 1.5 at the same place of 1.4.2. Go 1.5 does not use C anymore and if old C installation files are present it throws the error as you are shown.

if you want the old installation to be present as well then install 1.5 to some other location and set GOROOT to that location.

Hope it helps.

**Edit 1: For Linux Users:**

if you downloaded go1.5*.tar.gz then you did this:

> tar -C /usr/local/ -xvf go1.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz

Your old folder C files are not deleted, so the correct process is:

First: You should delete you old go folder.

> sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go/

Second: Then run

> tar -C /usr/local/ -xvf go1.5.x.linux-amd64.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my problems too. 
I had two imports of "imports runtime" and tried everything - I even removed code that I added because I didn't expect that a upgrade from go1.4 to go1.5 could have caused this.

Comment: Could you explain a little more @deFreitas

Comment: @MayankPatel Even after run as you suggest and installing `golang 1.6.2` I still getting `C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG` the error example is [here](https://github.com/mageddo/go-examples/tree/master/id). my CGO_ENABLED="1" env is enabled and gcc installed but simply no work

Comment: There can be many reason for getting this error. Make sure correct version (32/64 bit) of gcc is installed. Try Adding a new file in the package and importing C package in it. something like package p import "C" @deFreitas

Comment: @MayankPatel By the code [author comment](https://github.com/davecheney/junk/issues/2#issuecomment-236319172) apparently that is a deprecated code style for the new golang compiles

Answer (score 5):

If you use `brew` to upgrade your go to Go 1.5.  Here is my step to make it work:

1. Remove pkg folder in %GOPATH%
2. Reload terminal(console) session, make sure `Go env` goes to Go 1.5 folder.

BTW: You need do the same thing if you want to switch from Go 1.5 back Go 1.4.2 via `brew switch go 1.4.2`.

Comment: Although cleaning out `$GOPATH/pkg` can be helpful (it's not strictly required as `go build` and `go install` should just recognize the contents as stale and re-build things as required) it is unrelated to the OP's issue which was having old `*.c` source files from Go1.4 left in `$GOROOT/src`. You should never install a new verion of Go over-top a previous installation but into a fresh location (i.e. move/delete the old installation first).

Comment: I can't use go1.4.2, (because I need to import encoding/json), what can I resolve this problem in go1.5?

Comment: This just happened to me with brew - it does indeed install to different folders, but for some reason the go tool uses the old install until I start a new terminal session. Reloading the terminal fixes the issue.

Comment: @dmikalova Yes, thats's what I mean. I just edit my answer for that. Reloading terminal(console) session.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem because I installed two version of golang on my machine, one from offical site and the other is from homebrew.

And the GOROOT isn't match the go binary, I just replace the GOROOT with the right one, then done.

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec # install via brew
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue within my editor (sublime text 2). I call go build upon saving, it would appear my editor was pointing to go 1.4.x rather than the newly installed 1.5.

- I solved this by simply quitting and reopening my editor.