# package .: C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG: main.c

Tags: linux, go

For simplicity, I created two "Hello World" programs in the same directory, called `main.go` and `main.c`.

Golang:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And both programs compile and run okay:

[image: hello world in Golang and C]

But as you can see, VSCode is giving me an error that says:

> package .: C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG:
> main.c

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115271/6282576), I have to **remove** and **reinstall** Go, and install the newer version that is above 1.5. So I ran this command to see where it's installed:

```
$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

And then I removed that directory:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go
```

Now the command no longer works:

```
$ go version
zsh: command not found: go
$ which go
go not found
```

To make sure, I also deleted the `go` directory in `$HOME`:

```
$ sudo rm -rf $HOME/go
```

I also checked to see if I may have installed it through `pacman`, but there's no `go` package in the output:

```
$ pacman -Q | grep go
argon2 20190702-3
go-tools 2:1.14+3923+c00d67ef2-1
haskell-vector-algorithms 0.8.0.3-21
pango 1:1.44.7+11+g73b46b04-1
pangomm 2.42.1-2
```

Then I downloaded and extracted [`go1.15.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz`](https://golang.org/dl/go1.15.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz) into `/usr/local/`:

```
$ sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.15.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Now I can see that it's installed:

```
$ go version
go version go1.15.3 linux/amd64
$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

I also have this directory in the `$PATH`, as I add this `export` command in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Now I close VSCode and reopen it, but the same error is there.

[One answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33095123/6282576) that the `$GOROOT` variable must be set to the right directory, currently this variable for me is empty. So I add this `export` in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

But the error is still there. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to

```
package main
import(
    "fmt
)
import "C"
func main() {
...
}
```

and you need to change the c function name from `main()` to something else in your `C` file to avoid multiple definition of it when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

**"C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG"** that means you have a main.c file in the same folder of main.go, but you are not using it like **cgo**

Solution: Put main.c in another folder